# using htaccess to load page for certain domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain example.com and mainexample.com- i want a example.com to point to mainexample.com/social/pre/register/121 which already driven by the htaccess file.

I am not sure how to go about this.. I have pointed the two domains at the same directory. I'm on a virtual shared server so I am using directadmin with php/codeigniter.

The site uses the standard htaccess file for codeigniter listed below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /upd8r_jul

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to add slashes to the `%{REQUEST_URI}` lines, because they all look like `/something` and not `something` like the URI's used against matches in `RewriteRule`'s. But that does affect the question you're asking.

If you want to redirect `http://example.com/` to `http://mainexample.com/social/pre/register/121` then add these rules **above** the rules you already have in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mainexample.com/social/pre/register/121 [L,R=301]
```